# Prestashop override admin template

Tags: php, prestashop-1.5

I have the code (for prestashop 1.5):

```
class AdminTestController extends AdminController
{
    public $identifier = 'id_test';
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = 'test';
        $this->className = 'test';

        /*$this->fields_list = array(
        'id_test' => array('title' => $this->l('ID'), 'align' => 'center', 'width' => 25),
        'content' => array('title' => $this->l('Test'), 'width' => 'auto')
        );*/

        $this->fields_options = array(
                    'general' => array(
                    'title' =>  $this->l(''),
                    'icon' =>   'tab-preferences',
                    'fields' => array(
                            'TEST' =>  array(
                            'type' => 'textarea',
                            'label' => $this->l('TEST'),
                            'title' => $this->l('TEST'),
                            'name' => 'test',
                            'autoload_rte' => true,
                            'lang' => true,
                            'rows' => 15,
                            'cols' => 70,
                            //'hint' => $this->l('Invalid    characters:').' <>;=#{}'
                            )
                    ),
                    'submit' => array(
                                'title' => $this->l('Save'),
                                'class' => 'button'
                            )       
                    )
                );
    }
}
```

I want to attach tinyMCE to my textarea. I need to override one template but I can't find which one.

I tried:

template/controllers/test/list/list.tpl
template/controllers/test/form.form.tpl

How can I override the template for my controller?

Answer (score 0):

Just for information. I override option/option.tpl; Now it works.